# How do I disable float numbers in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I am making a bot which tracks discord server stats and makes a graph of them.

While making the bot, I faced a problem. The bot shows floating point numbers in the graph which are not supposed to be there.

[image: Graph]

Is it possible to disable the float numbers and show only `12`, `13`, `14` instead of `12`, `12.25`, `12.50`, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

I suppose your data are in a `y` list. In this case you can use [`ax.set_yticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html) as here:

```
yticks = range(min(y), max(y) + 1)
ax.set_yticks(yticks)
```

### Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('dark_background')

x = ['14.09', '15.09', '16.09', '17.09', '18.09']
y = [12, 13, 13, 14, 14]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y, color = 'green', linestyle = '-', marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = 'red')
ax.set_facecolor('white')
ax.set_ylabel('Member count')
ax.set_title("Member count for 'СПГ'")
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)

yticks = range(min(y), max(y) + 1)
ax.set_yticks(yticks)

plt.show()
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It actually worked and float numbers are no more!